# How can I write a bash or awk script that reads numbers from txt file, and divide each number by a variable?

Tags: bash, awk

I have a sample text file as follow color.txt:

```
68.08602255 1.24295415 84.00087345 255
68.4701724 2.44923165 85.5337626 255
```

I want to write a bash script that allows me to go into each number and divide them by 255. These numbers are color values between 0-255, some programs require values between 0-1 instead. The values will only be divided by 255. The above text would have the following output

```
0.267004 0.00487433 0.329415 1
0.26851 0.00960483 0.335427 1
```

Comment: awk is not part of bash -- it's an entirely diferent language. If you want an awk script (and you should, awk is the better tool for the job), it's not a bash script, so there shouldn't be a bash tag on the question.

Comment: @anubhava, ...only missing thing is taking the 255 as a variable.

Comment: ok then `awk -v n=255 '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i /= n} 1' file`

Comment: 255 is probably not going to change.

Comment: is the last field relevant to what it is being divided by ?

Comment: [edit] your question to include the expected output given that input and tell us what the output should be when the variable you're dividing by has value zero.

Comment: @karakfa, dunno, 8-bit-per-channel isn't the only way colors are ever represented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh

var=255
awk -v var="$var" '{ print $1 / var, $2 / var, $3 / var, $4 / var }'
```